# Usa visa extension.

Tags: visas, usa

I am a Indian citizen currently in canada with valid visa for ten years with multiple entries. I also have a USA visa for ten years with multiple entries, which expires in early June 2018. I wish to extend my stay here.
Can I apply for USA visa from Canada?
Will it be a new visa?
Or extension to old USA visa which is up to Early June 2018.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the type of each visa and your desired itinerary.

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing. Are you in the US or Canada?

US visas are only for entry, and you would only apply for a new visa if you need to enter the US after the expiration of your current visa. If you are not planning to enter the US, you don't need a visa.

The visa's expiration date just means the last day on which you can use it to enter the US, and has absolutely nothing to do with how long you can stay in the US -- that is determined by your *status*.

If you are currently in the US and need to stay longer than the date on your I-94, you can apply for Extension of Status; this has nothing to do with your visa, and getting your status extended will not give you a visa (which is only for entry and thus can only be applied for outside the US, because if you are in the US, you don't need to "enter").

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a resident of Canada you will be required to go back to India to apply for another US visa. The non-immigrant US visas cannot be extended.

Comment: [It's possible to apply for an extension on a B visa](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/how-extend-your-stay-change-your-status-while-b-visa.html), though that would be from inside the US, not from Canada. It's expensive and takes months for a decision, but possible.

Comment: Do you have a source supporting your assertion that nonresidents cannot apply for a US B visa in Canada?  It contradicts everything I've heard on the subject.

Comment: @Zach Lipton, the difference between theory and practice matters in this case. Extending B visa is an exception not a norm, and the applicant needs to have a VERY GOOD reason to ask extension or it will be declined. However, it is relatively easier to apply to change their B status to other immigrant visas that allow studies or employment.

Comment: @phoog, in theory nonresidents can apply but in common practice applicants from most Asian and African countries are told to apply in the country of their origin or residence unless they have a COMPELLING reason to apply in a third country and able to justify it. Saying that you happen to be in Canada on tourism and would like to apply for a US B visa is not a compelling reason or a good excuse.